# calculate complex integral directly

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a complex integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_C \frac{1}{z^2(z-1)} dz,
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a circular contour centered at 0 with radius $R<1$. For such integral, by using the residue theorem, the final answer is $-2\pi i$.
However, my question is that I want to calculate this integral directly. Namely, define $z = Re^{i\theta}$ where $R<1$ and $\theta$ runs from 0 to $2\pi$. By substituting to the original integral, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_C\frac{1}{z^2(z-1)}dz = \frac{i}{R}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}(Re^{i\theta}-1)} d\theta.
\end{equation}
But how to go further to obtain the final result the $-2\pi i$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the integral as $\int_0^{2\pi} [\frac R {Re^{i\theta} -1} -\frac 1  {e^{i\theta}}] d\theta$. Separate out the two terms. The integral of the second term is $0$ so you only have to find the integral of the first term. For that you can use the fact that $\frac 1 {1-Re^{i\theta}} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} R^{n}e^{in\theta}$. The series converge uniformly and each term after the first one integrates to $0$.